# Prevent use of a class outside of temporary scope?

Tags: c++, c++03

Is there a way to tell if an instance has been constructed in temporary scope or not, or prevent it from being used outside of temporary scope?  I'm guessing there's not, but then again, I'm always surprised by the ability of C++ to exceed its own design limitations.

It's kind of a weird question, I admit, and I don't know how to "justify" the desire short of just providing the backstory.

The question arises from a shuttle class we use to glue together a scary number of legacy systems, each with their own notion of how data is represented.  For a familiar example, take strings.  We could overload each method in our API with each "style" of string:

```
void some_method(const char* arg);
void some_method(const std::string& arg);
void some_method(const QString& arg);
void some_method(const XmlDocString& arg);
void some_method(const wire_string& arg);
```

Or we could do:

```
void some_method(const StringArg& arg);
```

Where that helper class is (let's ignore string encodings for now and just assume bad old C-style strings for the purposes of this question):

```
class StringArg {
public:
  StringArg() : m_data(""), m_len(0) {}
  template<size_t N>
  StringArg(const char (&s)[N]) : m_data(s), m_len(N-1) {}
  StringArg(const char* s) : m_data(s?s:"") { m_len = strlen(m_data); }      
  template<class T>
  StringArg(const T& t) : m_data(data_from(t)), m_len(len_from(t)) {}
  const char* data() const { return m_data; }
  const char* size() const { return m_len; }
private:
  const char* m_data;
  size_t m_len;
};

const char* data_from(const std::string& s) { return s.c_str(); }
size_t len_from(const std::string& s) { return s.size(); }

template<class XmlType>
const char* data_from(const XmlString<XmlType>& s) { return &s.content()[0]; }
template<class XmlType>
size_t len_from(const XmlString<XmlType>& s) { return s.byte_length(); }
```

ADL chooses the various data_from()/len_from() to get us a buffer backed by something else and its size.  In reality there's extra metadata to capture important information about the nature of the buffer and how to iterate it, but the important point for this discussion is that StringArg is used in temporary scope, is cheap to copy, provides fast access to some buffer backed by something else on the outside of the interface whose type we now don't actually need to care about, and that any conversion, argument checking, or length calculations are done once at the boundary.

So there we are, someone is free to call it with two wildly different string classes:

```
interface_method(header() + body.str() + tail(), document.read().toutf8());
```

We don't need to care about the lifetime or the type of whatever's going on here, and internally we can pass around pointers to those buffers like candy, slice them up, parse them, log them in triplicate, without accidental allocation or lengthy memory copies.  As long as we never *hang on* to those buffers, internally, this is safe and fast and has been a joy to maintain.

But as this API becomes more widely used, StringArg is (perhaps unsurpisingly) being used in places other than temporary scope, as if it were Yet Another String Class, and the resulting fireworks are impressive.  Consider:

```
std::string t("hi");
write(StringArg(t+t)); //Yes.
StringArg doa(t+t); //NO!
write(doa); //Kaboom?
```

`t+t` creates a temporary whose content StringArg will point into.  In temporary scope this is routine, nothing interesting to see here.  Outside of it, of course, it's insanely dangerous.  Dangling pointers to random stack memory.  Of course, the second call to write() actually will work *just fine* most of the time, even though it is most clearly wrong, which makes detecting these mistakes quite difficult.

And here we are.  I want to allow:

```
void foo(const StringArg& a);

foo(not_string_arg());
foo(t+t);
```

I want to prevent or detect:

```
StringArg a(t+t); //No good
```

And I'd be fine if the following wasn't possible, too, even though it's fine:

```
foo(StringArg(t+t)); //Meh
```

If I could detect the scope this thing was being constructed in, I could actually go and arrange to copy the content into a stable buffer in the constructor, similar to std::string, or throw an exception at runtime, or even better, if I could prevent it at compile time that'd ensure it was only used as designed.

Really, though, I only want StringArg to ever be the type of a method argument.  An end user will never have to type "StringArg" in order to use the API.  Ever.  You'd hope that'd be easy enough to document away, but once some code looks like it works, it multiplies, and multiplies...

I have tried making StringArg non-copyable but that doesn't help much.  I have tried creating an additional shuttle class and a non-const reference to try and fake out the implicit conversions in such a way they go my way.  The explicit keyword seems to make my problem worse, promoting the typing of "StringArg".  I tried messing around with an additional struct with partial specialization which is the only thing that knows how to construct a StringArg, and hiding the constructors for StringArg... something like:

```
template<typename T> struct MakeStringArg {};
template<> struct MakeStringArg<std::string> { 
  MakeStringArg(const std::string& s); 
  operator StringArg() const;
}
```

So then the user has to wrap all arguments with MakeStringArg(t+t) and MakeFooArg(foo) and MakeBarArg(bar)... existing code doesn't compile and in any case it kind of kills joy of using the interface.

I'm not above macro hacks at this point.  My bag of tricks is looking pretty empty about now.  Anyone have any advice?

Comment: What is "temporary scope" ?

Comment: It's relatively simple to make `foo(doa)` cause an error in most cases in C++98/03 by simply providing an undefined `foo(StringArg &)` overload. Unless `doa` is declared `const`, `foo(doa)` will prefer `foo(StringArg &)`, which will cause a linker error. In C++11/14, you can make `foo` accept `StringArg &&` only, so that `foo(doa)` simply will never compile without an explicit cast.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Apparently that `StringArg` can only be created as a temporary. If only the language allowed ref-qualified constructors...

Comment: A better design might be to make `some_method` templates, and then use trait classes to provide `data()` and `size()` etc. for each type of string you want to support. But I assume that it's too late for such a radical design change...

Comment: Even if you can only construct temporaries of this type, it does not guarantee no dangling references, e.g. `StringArg const &s = t + t;`

Comment: That's a good idea, T.C.: just provide foo(StringArg&) overload and don't implement it.  That will catch some cases.  Matt McNabb has a good point that it's not the scope I care about, so much as a usable instance of StringArg escaping the full-expression in which it was constructed.

Answer (score 1):

So Matt McNabb points out

```
std::string t("hi");
const StringArg& a = t + t;
```

This causes a temporary StringArg to live longer than the content it points to.  What I actually need is a way to determine when the full expression in which StringArg was constructed has ended.  And that's actually doable:

```
class StringArg {
public:
  template<class T>
  StringArg(const T& t, const Dummy& dummy = Dummy()) 
    : m_t(content_from(t)), m_d(&dummy) {
    m_d->attach(this);
  }
  ~StringArg() { if (m_d) m_d->detach(); }
private:
  void stale() {
    m_t = ""; //Invalidate content
    m_d = NULL; //Don't access dummy anymore
    //Optionally assert here
  }
  class Dummy {
  public:
    Dummy() : inst(NULL) {}
    ~Dummy() { if (inst) inst->stale(); }
    void attach(StringArg* p) { inst = p; }
    void detach() { inst = NULL; }
    StringArg* inst;
  };
  friend class Dummy;
private:
  const char* m_t;
  Dummy* m_d;
};
```

With this, Matt's example and all the others I was hoping to prevent are thwarted: when the full expression ends, no StringArg points to anything suspect any longer, so any StringArg "given a name" is guaranteed to be useless.

(In case it's not clear why this works, it's because a Dummy must have been constructed before a StringArg that uses it, and therefore StringArg is guaranteed to be destroyed before the Dummy unless its lifetime is greater than the full expression in which it was constructed.)

Answer (score 0):

I admit I didn't read your entire post, but you seem to have conflicting requirements. On the one hand you state that you want to avoid dangling references, but then you write:

```
write(StringArg(t+t)); //Yes.
StringArg doa(t+t); //NO!
```

If your only concern is to avoid dangling references then change the "NO!" to a "Yes", and in both cases move out of the temporary into a local value. The constructor would be:

```
StringArg(std::string &&arg)
{
     this->the_arg = std::move(arg);
}
```

where `the_arg` is a `std::string`.

You could have `StringArg` store the string when it was constructed from an rvalue, and hold a reference to a string if it was constructed from an lvalue.

Comment: You forgot the point that the thing is supposed to be cheap to copy (and also wrap a variety of types beyond `std::string`).

Comment: It could contain a variant, or it could have the type of string as a template parameter. "cheap to copy" might not actually be a requirement, if moving is possible instead of copying.

Comment: @TC he already has `const char* m_data;  size_t m_len;` in his class, changing that to a string type doesn't add any difficulty

Answer (score 0):

If you want a class which methods could be used only by rvalue objects, you could use rvalue qualifier on methods in C++11:

```
class only_rvalue
{
public:
    only_rvalue() = default;
    only_rvalue( const only_rvalue& ) = delete; 
    only_rvalue( only_rvalue&& ) = default;

    only_rvalue& operator=( const only_rvalue&& ) = delete;
    only_rvalue& operator=( only_rvalue&& ) = default;

    void foo() &&;
    void bar() &&;
    void quux() &&;
};

only_rvalue create();

int main()
{
    only_rvalue{}.foo(); //ok
    create().bar(); //ok

    only_rvalue lvalue;
    lvalue.foo(); //ERROR
}
```